# Encrypt shared files on AD Domain to prevent leaks

Tags: security, encryption, active-directory

Title is basically a copy of an old question posted on this forum, but due to having a scenario where it wouldn't apply very well, old OP haven't had it answered.

Can I encrypt shared folders on Windows Server and allow only authenticated domain users have access to these files?

My main goal is to prevent the files from being opened / read from a machine outside of my domain network.

I'm really worried about ransomware attacks, and have the backup side of things covered, so data loss is not my main concern. However, It would be really bad if the ransomware attack copy our files to the cloud, and release them in the wild.

We have bitlocker enabled, but, from my understanding, it would only protect against physical access to the drive, and whilst it's running, everything on the server is already decrypted and available to be read / copied. So BitLocker is not an solution.

My idea is to encrypt the shared folders and files using certificates / keys that are installed via GPO on machines that are on our network. If the user logs on using AD, it gets the key, and can read/write the files, but if one were to copy it (the file, not the content obviously) to an external location it wouldn't be readable at all.

Is this a viable solution to preventing data leaks? Or are there other methods that would be more effective on this particular case?

Comment: What happens if the malware infects the user's machine and runs _as_ that user?

Comment: Even if it copy the file in that case, it most likely won't copy the key (stored on the AD server), and the file would be unreadable on any machine other than the local one withouth the key. Right?

Comment: Yes, but loosing acces to the file is not my main concern, as I already have a backup policy in place. I just want to make sure no one outside of my network can open the files.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the proper NTFS permissions and Share permissions will prevent unauthenticated users and devices from connecting to your shares.

Enabling [SMB Encryption](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/smb-security) can protect data from eavesdropping on untrusted networks, but will not prevent data exfiltration if an authenticated user or computer is compromised.

If you're specific concern is preventing data exfiltration then you'll be looking at either heavily restricting how users access the data (you'll have to prevent direct access to network shares and have them connect through some other mechanism with greater control on data flow) or you'll be implementing Data Loss Prevention software - or a combination of several things.

I would recommend that you start research on Data Loss Prevention and that will lead you down many rabbit holes with potential answers to your specific concerns.

Here is a good link with more information:
[Data Loss Prevention](https://blog.netwrix.com/2020/02/11/data-loss-prevention-dlp/)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I encrypt shared folders on windows server and allow only authenticated domain users have access to these files?

Encryption does not prevent files from being leaked by users who can decrypt a file, and in order to (view and modify) a file, you can do exactly that.  **This means if a user wants to copy a file on the network share to a removable flash storage device, the copy of the file isn't encrypted.**

> I'm really worried about ransomware attacks, and have the backup side of things covered, so data loss is not my main concern. However, It would be really bad if the ransomware attack copy our files to the cloud, and release them in the wild.

Protecting a network share with BitLocker WILL NOT prevent ransomware from encrypting any files a user has write access to since ransomware typically attempts to encrypt any file the user that ran it has access to.

> We already have BitLocker enabled, but, from my understanding, it would only protect against physical access to the drive, and whilst it's running, everything on the server is already decrypted and available to be read / copied

BitLocker is indeed designed to prevent attaching the physical disk drive to another computer.

> My idea is to encrypt the shared folders and files using certificates / keys that are installed via GPO on machines that are on our network. If the user logs on using AD, it gets the key, and can read/write the files, but if one were to copy it (the file, not the content obviously) to an external location it wouldn't be readable at all.

**EFS will prevent copying the file.  However, a user can decrypt the file since they have write access to the copy of the file.  However, EFS will not prevent ransomware from encrypting that same file.**

> Is this a viable solution to preventing data leaks? Or are there other methods that would be more effective on this particular case?

EFS and BitLocker does not prevent data from being copied to a external removable device.  There are solutions to that problem.  **EFS and BitLocker is not that solution.**

> my main goal is to prevent the files from being opened / read from a machine outside of my domain network

As a hostile attacker, one cannot simply plug in a machine and connect to an AD domain.  The system must be configured to connect to the domain, and the active directory domain must acknowledge that it can access it.

Furthermore, your network cannot be accessed outside your network, and a physical attack is your only real risk.  So configure switch ports to be disabled by default, ports locked to specific machines unless unlocked, and use the appropriate tools (2FA) to protect all manufacturer's accounts if those switches are remotely configured.

BitLocker makes it impossible to take the HDD from the machine and put it into another device. Even if that were to happen, they couldn’t access your network shares due to needing a domain account with the appropriate permissions.

If they have physical access to those terminals, then BitLocker and strong password rules prevent access to your network. EFS will encrypt the user files within their profile, and this means if, for some reason, they can bypass and decrypt the entire drive, they would still need the certificate and that passphrase to access the files.

Meanwhile, the share drive is still off limits due to needing a machine on the domain and authenticated as a user account with permissions.

A machine from outside your AD domain could access your files on your network share if they accessed the share using an account on the domain. This means the machine was added to the Active Directory domain. Otherwise, copying the file to an external drive would be the only other way.

> I want to prevent the files (if uploaded) from being opened on machines that have not ingressed in our local network only domain.

Resource protection systems exist, but **encrypting files** is not that protection.  If a user on your domain copies a file to a flash device and opens it on their laptop, they can easily replicate that file.

Comment: “Encryption does not prevent files from being leaked by users who can decrypt a file, and in order to (view and modify) a file, you can do exactly that.” Bingo! Encryption is not magic. If someone has access to the file/data that is decrypted for normal human use, anything can happen.